# How to install dependent rpm packages in puppet

Tags: puppet

I tried to write puppet script to install lustre.luster needs installation of kernel patch and then lustre package installation. How to handle dependency in puppet while installing rpm package

Comment: Read [Relationships and Ordering](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html) section in Puppet documentation.

Comment: Do be mindful that a puppet *manifest* is conceptually quite different from a script.